Firebase init, deploy no errors; but why the website not showing
I did npm npm run build, firebase init and firebase deploy on vscode.
(base) PS C:\xampp\htdocs\episode2> firebase deploy
=== Deploying to 'azlife-a8cb2'...
i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[azlife-a8cb2]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[azlife-a8cb2]: found 1 files in y

hosting[azlife-a8cb2]: file upload complete
i  hosting[azlife-a8cb2]: finalizing version...

hosting[azlife-a8cb2]: version finalized
i  hosting[azlife-a8cb2]: releasing new version...

hosting[azlife-a8cb2]: release complete

Deploy complete!


Then I click the hosting url, it shows

I have no problems the day earlier. I keep working on the codes and cannot open the hosting url. It is really weired. Really appreciate it if you can provide any suggestions!
